# Python Keeping track of changes

Tags: python, database, csv

I'm trying to identify new, and terminated transaction from month to month using python 2.7.

I have a .csv that can be 2-3GB large containing say 4 months so I'm looking for a solution that is as quick as possible instead of putting large dictionaries in memory and iterating over them. In this csv the data looks like this:

date,uniqueID,highLevelClientDetail

I'm wondering how to output summary statistics for each month of total number (continued uniqueID, terminated, new). 
EDIT: Where continued unique ID refers to an ID that appears in month 1 and 2, terminated means it appears in month 1 but not 2, and new refers to it being in month 2 but not month 1

Normally, I'd put this into a statistical software and do it with 2 lines but I'm limited to using python and have never used it in this way.

Comment: Is the data ordered by date?

Comment: You can probably do this in a few lines of Python too, but you need to be more specific. What do you mean by *continued uniqueID*, *terminated*, and *new*. This doesn't mean anything at all to me.

Comment: yes the data is order by date. Sorry continued unique ID refers to an ID that appears in month 1 and 2, terminated means it appears in month 1 but not 2, and new refers to it being in month 2 but not month 1